# How to create a slider with double check?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

I wanted to create an app, that take an audio file, and through a control (the slider or similar) would allow with a double cursor to select the start point and final audio file then split it. What control I could use? I need a custom control?

Comment: useful link: http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Creating_a_Range_Slider_in_WPF_and_other_cool_tips_and_tricks_for_UserControls_.aspx,  looks like it can be converted to use wp8 template using thumbs.

Comment: You can try [Infragistics slider](http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-phone/interactions/slider).